# Chrome background image render issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Background image is not render properly, Background image appear when I select text around it. I tried to remove javascript or some code but still it's acting like that. First I thought it's caching issue but this is happening in localhost also. Here is the [Demo video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mdGNdx4bF8a01mekVjZUdjenc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: The video is great, but it would help more if you post the relevant code

Comment: Code is normal it is a bootstrap site. URL is in Video I can't write here.

Comment: Does this happen, when you open with a 'fresh' chrome process?

Comment: Yes even in private mode. It was happening because google fonts was just before body tag, after all css and js.

Comment: @MikulGohil 'Code is normal' That's a good one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Load your `.css` before you load your `.js`

Comment: thanks problem was loading google fonts after css and javascript.

Comment: Sorry issue is because of animation.css https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mdGNdx4bF8Tnh6WjJ1RVkxd00/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I think the image file is a bit two big (532KB). Try to reduce the file size with [RIOT](http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/) or similar. I managed to reduce it to 96 KB (JPG 77%, Chroma subsampling Medium 4:2:0, Progressive) without any substantial quality loss.

Also you should try to reorganize the order of your code. Whene it's possible move all JavaScript to the bottom (right before closing of `body` tag)

Comment: check this Sorry issue is because of animation.css https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mdGNdx4bF8Tnh6WjJ1RVkxd00/edit?usp=sharing